# ReactJS access to object into object with map and Object.keys()

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I have problem to get information in my arrayin ReactJS.

That is the array I'm trying to read (it appears like this in my Terminal :

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, createdAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', updatedAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', Justices: Array(1), Interieurs: Array(1), …}
1: {id: 2, createdAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:21.000Z', updatedAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:21.000Z', Justices: Array(1), Interieurs: Array(1), …}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

[image]

And that is when you click on index O :

[image]

```
0:
AffaireEtrangeres: [{…}]
Agricultures: [{…}]
Armees: [{…}]
Cultures: [{…}]
Ecologies: [{…}]
EconomieFinances: [{…}]
EducationNationales: [{…}]
Interieurs: [{…}]
Justices: Array(1)
0: {id: 1, firstName: 'justice', lastName: 'justiceNom', createdAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', updatedAt: '2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z', …}
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
OutreMers: [{…}]
Santes: [{…}]
Sports: [{…}]
Travails: [{…}]
createdAt: "2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z"
id: 1
updatedAt: "2022-03-07T08:17:01.000Z"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

So, it look something like that :

```
const governmentList = [
    {
        id: "",
        _date: "",
        infoMain: {
            idInfo: "",
            firstName: "",
            LastName: ""
        },
        infoSecond: {
            idInfo: "",
            firstName: "",
            LastName: ""
        },
        infoThird: {
            idInfo: "",
            firstName: "",
            LastName: ""
        }
    },
    {
        id: "",
        _date: "",
        infoMain: {
            idInfo: "",
            firstName: "",
            LastName: ""
        },
        infoSecond: {
            idInfo: "",
            firstName: "",
            LastName: ""
        },
        infoThird: {
            idInfo: "",
            firstName: "",
            LastName: ""
        }
    },
    //etc...
]
```

I want to get `firstName` value of each object of my index 0, then 1, then 2...:

```
<Box>
                <Grid>

                    {governmentList.map((value, key) =>
                    (


                        <Grid>
                            <Paper>

                                {Object.keys(value).map((key) => {
                                        console.log(value[key][0].firstName)
                                })}
                            </Paper>
                        </Grid>
                    )
                    )};
                </Grid>
            </Box >
```

But my terminal return me an error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName')
```

Do you have any ideas to solve my issu please ?

Comment: None of the object properties are arrays, so `value[key][0]` is always going to be undefined. Also, not all of the properties are objects with a firstname sub-property, some are strings.

Comment: In your data you have an array with a key, values. Its wrong. You can have an array of objects of an object with key value. Thus, `const governmentList = [{id: "",...}, ...rest]` or 
`const governmentList = {0: {id: "",...}, 1: {...}, ...}`

Comment: I added news informations in my post. I hope that will help you to detect my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have copied the data from the console I think. Your data is as follows, right?

```
const governmentList = [
  {
    id: "",
    _date: "",
    infoMain: {
        idInfo: "",
        firstName: "",
        LastName: ""
    },
    infoSecond: {
        idInfo: "",
        firstName: "",
        LastName: ""
    },
    infoThird: {
        idInfo: "",
        firstName: "",
        LastName: ""
    }
},
 {
      id: "",
      _date: "",
      infoMain: {
          idInfo: "",
          firstName: "",
          LastName: ""
      },
      infoSecond: {
          idInfo: "",
          firstName: "",
          LastName: ""
      },
      infoThird: {
          idInfo: "",
          firstName: "",
          LastName: ""
      }
  },
  //etc...
]
```

You can loop throug it as follows:

```
{governmentList.map((item) => {
    return Object.keys(item).map((key) => {
      if (item[key] && item[key]["firstName"]) {
        return <div>Name: {item[key]?.firstName}</div>;
      }
    });
})}
```

Check if key and firstName exist with `item[key] && item[key]["firstName"]` and the do the rest

UPDATE

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-fiddle-forked-hy8k87?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Actually `item[key]?.firstName` prevents an error if `item[key]` doesn't exist  NOT `firstName`. But accessing a property that doesn't exist doesn't throw an error, so that's fine. Because you are using `Object.keys` `item[key]` will always exist, so it's unnecessary. I would do: `return item[key].firstName ? <div>Name: {item[key].firstName}</div> : null` so you never render an empty div.

Comment: ok, thanks you for this idea, but I get `undefined` value everytime. I add news informations in my post. I hope that will help you to detect my porblem.

Comment: @Renjus It works with the data that you've added. I've update the answer with the link to the Sandbox where you can see that it works. Add correct FULL data that you use.

Answer (score -1):

Can You Try this one

```
{Object.keys(value).map((key) => {
       console.log(value[key][0].firstName&&value[key][0].firstName)
                                 })}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I added news informations in my post. I hope that will help you to detect my problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).